# Azure Dev Ops/VSTS Query to return PBIs related to a specific epic whith a hierarchy of Epic -> Feature -> PBI

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to create a query in Azure Dev Ops (formerly VSTS) that will return all the PBIs that are under a particular epic.

Using the below example I would search for Epic "Sort and Filter Task List" and be returned all the PBIs below but not the features.

**The backlog**

**Hierarchy Screen Shot**

[image: Screen Shot]
**Search for Epic "269661: Sort and Filter Task List" return the below**

**Results**

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

Create a query, in the "**Type of query**" choose "**Tree of work items**", then in the second section (the links) in "**Work Item Type**" type **"Product Backlog Item"**.

[image]
As you can see, in the results I got the PBI's under the Epic but with the Features also.

Comment: Hello, thanks I have done this before but I am specifically trying to find a way to not show the features or epics in the results as I intend to use this query in a dashboard.

Comment: Yes please, only the PBIs